# Angular JS, multiple insert error

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to fetch data from SQL and display in HTML table using `ng-repeat` option then I need to edit some values in the table cell. My problem is that I only get initial values in the controller and the changes are not reflected in the controller. Here is my code:

```
app.controller('CRUD_EntryController', function ($scope, CRUD_InternalEntryService) {

GetStudentMarkDetails();

function GetStudentMarkDetails() {
    var PromiseGetMarks = CRUD_InternalEntryService.GetMarkDetails();
    PromiseGetMarks.then(function (res) {
        $scope.MarkList = res.data;
    })

}
$scope.mark = {};
$scope.save = function (MarkList) {

    var index = 0;
    $scope.MarkList.forEach(function (mark) {
        console.log('rows #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(mark));
        alert(mark.M1);
    }

}
```

View:

```
    <table class=" table table-condensed" id="myresul">  
        <tr>  
            <th>Slno</th>  
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>RegNo</th>
            <th>ClassNo</th>
            <th>M1</th>
            <th>M2</th>
            <th>M3</th>
        </tr>  

        <tbody data-ng-repeat="mark in MarkList" >  
            <tr>  
            <td class="col-md-1"  >#{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2" ng-model="mark.Fname">{{mark.Fname}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">{{mark.RegNo}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">{{mark.ClassNo}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><input type="number" value="{{mark.M1}}" ng-model="M1" class="form-control" /></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><input type="number" value="{{mark.M2}}" ng-model="M2" class="form-control" /></td>
            <td class="col-md-1"><input type="number" value="{{mark.M3}}" ng-model="M3" class="form-control" /></td>

            </tr>  
            <button data-ng-click="save(MarkList)" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </tbody>  

    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you need to define this: `$scope.mark = {};` since mark is set in the scope of your ng-repeat. Remove it because this is somewhat confusing and might cause errors in the future.

Remove the `value="{{mark.M1}}"` and bind your model to `ng-model="{{mark.M1}}"`. Asuming that you wand to bind to M1, M2 and M3 in your inputs.

Also see the [angular docs for ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for more details and update your code accordingly.

By the way you don't have to pass `MarkList` as an argument for `Save(..)`, you can do this:
`<button data-ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>`, change the `Save` method signature to `Save()` and use `$scope.MarkList` instead of the argument `MarkList`.

Or change your method to only save the specific `mark` instead of the entire list every time.

Comment: No problem! Please mark it as answerd if the problem is solved.